# The content on my website is scrolling outside of screen

Tags: html, css, web

I have a website (madmonkeygunboats.com) and I am trying to fix a small problem where the page width is wider than the content.

If you go to the website and hold middle mouse button + move the mouse around, the toolbar and logo slide to the left and right.

I am really new to website development, and I was wondering if there is any way I can reduce the page width so this over scrolling issue stops?

Here is the style.css file:

```
        html, body {
    height:100%;
    padding: -100px;
    /*width:100%; /*Trying to lock horizontal scrolling*/
    overflow:hidden; /*Used to hide scroll bars*/
}
* {
    outline:none;
}
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background:#000;
    font-family:'Century Gothic', arial, serif;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7, h8 {
    font-family:"Jing Jing", "Jing Jing", sans-serif;
}
hgroup {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
    left:0%;
    top:715px; /*Moving Logo*/
    padding:0px;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:"Jing Jing", "Jing Jing", sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-shadow:#FFF 0 1px 1px;
}
hgroup h1 {
    margin: 0px;
    text-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 3px 2px 0;
    color:#F00;
    font-size: 150%;

}
hgroup h4 {
    font-family:'Century Gothic', arial, serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-indent:130px;
    margin: 0px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 3px 2px 0;

}
hgroup h7 {
    margin: 0px;
    text-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 3px 2px 0;
    color:#F00;
}
p1 {
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:'Century Gothic', arial, serif; 
}

hgroup a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #FFF;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #FFF;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
hgroup a:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
#toolbar {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:3;
    right:10px;
    top:10px;
    padding:5px;
    /*background:url(images/fs_img_g_bg.png);*/

}
#Logo {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:4;
    left:10px;
    top:10px;
    padding:5px;
    background:url(images/fs_img_g_bg.png);

}
#toolbar img {
    border:none;
}
#img_title {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:3;
    right:10px;
    bottom: 55%;
    padding:10px;
    /*background:url(images/fs_img_g_bg.png);*/
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:"Myriad Pro", "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    text-transform:camelcase;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#bg {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    /*background: url(images/dotted.png);*/
    opacity: 0.3;
}
#bgimg {
    display:none;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
#preloader {
    position:relative;
    z-index:3;
    width:32px;
    padding:20px;
    top:80px;
    margin:auto;
    background:#000;
}
#thumbnails_wrapper {
    z-index:2;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:100%;
    width:100%;
    height: 205px;
    top: -6px; /*Moving the Image slideshow thing*/
    background:url(images/empty.gif);
}
#outer_container {
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    margin:4px auto;
}
#outer_container .thumbScroller {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    /*background:url(images/fs_img_g_bg.png);*/
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.850);
}
#outer_container .thumbScroller, #outer_container .thumbScroller .container, #outer_container .thumbScroller .content {
    height:170px;
}
#outer_container .thumbScroller .container {
    position:relative;
    left:0;
}
#outer_container .thumbScroller .content {
    float:left;
}
#outer_container .thumbScroller .content div {
    margin:5px;
    height:100%;
}
#outer_container .thumbScroller img {
    border:3px solid #fff;
}
#outer_container .thumbScroller .content div a {
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
}
.nextImageBtn, .prevImageBtn {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    top:50%;
    margin:-25px 10px 0 10px;
    z-index:3;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
    -moz-opacity:0.4;
    -khtml-opacity:0.4;
    opacity:0.4;
    -webkit-transition:all .25s linear;
    -moz-transition:all .25s linear;
    -o-transition:all .25s linear;
    -ms-transition:all .25s linear;
    transition:all .25s linear;
}
.nextImageBtn:hover, .prevImageBtn:hover {
    filter:alpha(opacity=80);
    -moz-opacity:0.8;
    -khtml-opacity:0.8;
    opacity:0.8;
    -webkit-transition:all .25s linear;
    -moz-transition:all .25s linear;
    -o-transition:all .25s linear;
    -ms-transition:all .25s linear;
    transition:all .25s linear;
}
.nextImageBtn {
    right:0;
    background:#000 url(images/nextImgBtn.png) center center no-repeat;
}
.prevImageBtn {
    background:#000 url(images/prevImgBtn.png) center center no-repeat;
}
ul.menu {
    margin:0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style: none;
    font-family:"Myriad Pro", "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    width:60%;   /*For adding new tabs 850, 1020px*/
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
    /*left:40%*/
    right:-7%;  /*Moving Tab bar left or right*/
}
ul.menu a {
    text-decoration:none;
    outline:none;
}
ul.menu li {
    float:left;
    width:170px;
    height:85px;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
}
ul.menu li > a {
    position:absolute;
    top:70px;
    left:0px;
    width:170px;
    height:85px;
    z-index:12;
    background:transparent url(images/overlay.png) no-repeat bottom right;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
}
ul.menu li a img {
    border:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:85px;
    z-index:100;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000;
}
ul.menu li span.wrap {
    position:absolute;
    top:25px;
    left:0px;
    width:170px;
    height:60px;
    z-index:15;
}
ul.menu li span.active {
    position:absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    top:85px;
    width:170px;
    height:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:14;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px;
}
ul.menu li span span.link, ul.menu li span span.descr, ul.menu li div.box a {
    margin-left:15px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
}
ul.menu li span span.link {
    color:#fff;
    font-size:24px;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
ul.menu li span span.descr {
    color:#0B75AF;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    width:155px;
    font-size:10px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}
ul.menu li div.box {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:170px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:170px;
    top:85px;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
    background:#000;
}
ul.menu li div.box a {
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    line-height:30px;
    color:#0B75AF;
}
ul.menu li div.box a:first-child {
    margin-top:15px;
}
ul.menu li div.box a:hover {
    color:#fff;
}
article {
    display:none;
}
.image {
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: right;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
/* Pop Up */
#popupProject, #popupDesign, #popupModeling, #popupCoding, #popupDemo, #popupNews {
    height: 800px;
    width: 880px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
    border: 1px solid #cecece;
    z-index: 15;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#popupProject p, #popupDesign p, #popupModeling p, #popupCoding p, #popupDemo p, #popupNews p {
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
#popupProject h1, #popupDesign h1, #popupModeling h1, #popupCoding h1, #popupDemo h1, #popupNews h1 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #D3D3D3;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    margin: 0;
}
#popupProjectClose, #popupDesignClose, #popupModelingClose, #popupCodingClose, #popupDemoClose, #popupNewsClose {
    right: 0;
    top: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transition:all .25s linear;
    -moz-transition:all .25s linear;
    -o-transition:all .25s linear;
    -ms-transition:all .25s linear;
    transition:all .25s linear;
}
#popupProjectClose:hover, #popupDesignClose:hover, #popupModelingClose:hover, #popupCodingClose:hover, #popupDemoClose:hover, #popupNewsClose:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition:all .25s linear;
    -moz-transition:all .25s linear;
    -o-transition:all .25s linear;
    -ms-transition:all .25s linear;
    transition:all .25s linear;
}
.border {
    height: 3px;
    clear: both;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #FFF;
}
*:focus {
    outline: none;/* Prevents blue border in Webkit */
}
form {
    font-family:'Century Gothic', arial, serif;
    width: 350px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
input, textarea {
    font-family:"Myriad Pro", "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 30px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    color: #fff;
}
textarea {
    min-height: 200px;
    resize:none;
}
input:focus, textarea:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 25px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px #ccc;
}
/*working on revision*/
input:not(:focus), textarea:not(:focus) {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
input:required, textarea:required {
 background: url("images/asterisk_orange.png") no-repeat 280px 7px;
}
input:valid, textarea:valid {
 background: url("images/tick.png") no-repeat 280px 5px;
}
input:focus:invalid, textarea:focus:invalid {
 background: url("images/cancel.png") no-repeat 280px 7px;
}
input[type=submit] {
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: none;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
.map {
    margin-top: -500px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.30);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: right;
}
.date {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 44px 5px 0;
}
.date .month {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 25px;
}
.date .day {
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 0;
}
.date .year {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -5px;
    top: 15px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

I can provide html file if anyone needs it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes, please provide related HTML codes, or we don't know the structure of your page.

Comment: I'm not too sure about setting height: 100% on HTML and BODY elements.  That seems kind of funky to me, but I haven't tried that in the new days of CSS3 and modern browsers.

Also you're doing some really weird stuff here.  You set your background image up as part of a child element to BODY.  Why didn't you just set the background image on the body?  This page structure is very unusual and prone to problems.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to think about changing your layout to something more traditional. Are you familiar with this technique for background images?

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/how-to-css-large-background

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine here, so IE related yes?

Before you even try to fix you HAVE to fix your HTML+CSS. As it stands it's totally non-compliant and that's going to give you all kinds of grief. The [W3C validator service](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://madmonkeygunboats.com/) is your friend here.

Examples of messed up code:

- `<p1>` tags
- An XHTML DOCTYPE in the middle of your HTML5 document.
- Additional `<head>` tags inside your `<body>`
- Unclosed elements

While these problems exist browsers are free to cope with them anyway they feel like which means unreliable results.

Comment: SpliFF, its broke in Firefox for small resolution.  I'm on 1280x960.  I think that's what he's referring to.  Are you on HD?

Comment: It doesn't matter what size I make the window, I don't get the scrolling. FF 16, Linux.